# UITableViewCellSelection style doesn't properly work

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm developing an app using Xcode 4.5 and iOS 5.0.

In my app, i have a `UITableView` called **surveyTableView** created through **Storyboard**.
I want my `surveyTableView cell`s selected and i'm using this piece of code to make it happen.

```or-tag-here
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.surveyTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if(!cell)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell.textLabel.text = [[self.surveyInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SurveyName"];
            [cell setSelected:YES];
            return  cell ;
        }
```

I've only one section whose number of rows is 2 in this case.  Here is the image what i got on the screen. [image: Screenshot]

Do you guys any idea why this is happening ?

**EDIT** : I've set `UITableView selection attribute` to `Multiple Selection`, even if it's `Single Line Selection`, i realized that there is no difference.

**EDIT 2** : Here,i get image when ,i select `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`[image: Screenshot2]

**EDIT 3** : Here is the interesting part, when i select right now, here is the image.That's driving me crazy[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Try moving cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue; inside the if clause.  Oops,If that doesnt work keep the existing code and cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone inside the if clause.

Comment: @Renjith,it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: btw, why you want to make it selected?

Comment: what do you mean why ? it's designed like that

Comment: @downvoters : Seriously , do you have any reason why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that You should use `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` instead selected property for UITableViewCell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

by using this one you can select a cell always , and only change when you select an another cell

Comment: Wouw, i didn't see your response. I saw later and make it work thanks to u.

Answer (score 4):

please remove this  `[cell setSelected:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!cell)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            }
```

Comment: doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem, fixed it via setting attributes properly in storyboard.
Attaching the screenshot of tableview properties. Hope this helps you

[image]

Comment: I think here single selection is not possible,because i want all selected. There is no difference except selection attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to fetch the data from surveyTableView

```
NSString *cellValue= [[self.surveyInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SurveyName"];
NSLog(@"%@",cellValue);
```

check whether it's printing some values in console or not

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i fetch values.